# PHP file_get_contents() Suddenly Stopped Working

Tags: php, curl, nginx

My PHP file_get_contents() suddenly stopped working. I didn't made any changes, it was running fine before. But from today morning onwards it is getting timeout and my server is throwing bad gateway error.

I checked the same thing through command prompt using curl, it is working fine. Something is wrong with php.

Answer (score 4):

I solved the problem by forcing file_get_contents() to use IPV4. It seems like it was trying through IPV6 which does not having internet connection.

```
    $options = array(
        'socket' => array(
                      'bindto' => '0:0'
                    ),
       'http' => array(
       'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
       'method'  => 'POST',
       'content' => http_build_query($data)
      )
    );

    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Thanks.

Comment: thank you ! this was just what i needed to talk to google captcha :)